# jQuery Selectors :gt(a) issues

Tags: jquery

I want to generalize this function. I want to pass the value 'a' in :gt selector

```
            for (var a = 1; a < chge.length; a++) {

            if (document.getElementById('chge').value == a)
            {

                {
                    $('tr:gt(a)').css("display", "none");
                };
            }
        }

        }
```

it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this line:(putting `+` operator to **Concatenate** when you want to use value

```
$('tr:gt('+a+')').css("display", "none");
          ^ ^
```

**Explanation: if a=5**

```
console.log('tr:gt(a)');//output: tr:gt(a)

console.log('tr:gt('+a+')');//output: tr:gt(5)
```